# How do I know the font name from a non photoshop image?

Tags: image, image-processing, fonts, adobe, photoshop

I have an image that I managed using the *print screen* button. I want to know the name of the font that has been used at some place in the image. Is there a way I can manage to know the name of the font using photoshop ?

Answer (score 3):

If you found this online (vs a .pdf, .jpg, etc):

Using Google Chrome as your browser:
you can can go back to that site, select the font and right click select "Inspect Element". It will bring up an area through which you can see the css and therefore the font that the designer/developer used (unless they hid it, then searching through the 5 fonts suggested would be easier/faster).

AKA: find site using Google Chrome: select text in the font that you want --> right click --> select "Inspect Element" --> scroll through the CSS on the right hand side for "font-family"

Using any other browser: right click --> select "View Page Source" --> select the .css file --> find "font-family"

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in Photoshop. There exist some online tools that will attempt to detect fonts in images, such as this one: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: Unfortunately Photoshop is not a font detector. Assuming the image has been flattened (which it would be if you attained it using 'print screen'), Photoshop doesn't know the difference between the text and any other pixels in the image. If you narrowed it down to 5 fonts, it shouldn't be that difficult to type the same text with each of them and see which one looks identical to what you are looking for.